# HP WorkStation 8560w Enable FN keys

Tags: windows-8.1

in my HP WorkStation Laptop `EliteBook 8560` more than of 5 keys on `FN+Functinal` keys dont work. for example

```
Volume UP
Volume Down
Disable TouchPad Mouse
Change Brightness
```

i'm installing all drivers after install windows

Comment: Have you tried the `HP Support Assistant`? http://www8.hp.com/us/en/drivers.html --> `Detect my Product` --> `Find now`. I didn't have to install any driver by myself with that tool when I set up my HP notebook newly

Comment: yeah sounds like the needed software is missing - in my experience: it was often the synaptics software which was needed for the FN keys to work properly